# makefile "no rule to make a target" error

Tags: makefile

I have been looking at this problem for a while and still don't know what is wrong.

My makefile looks like:

```
    F90    = pgf90
NETCDF_DIR = /opt/netcdf

LBS             = -L$(NETCDF_DIR)/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
INCLUDE_MODULES = -I$(NETCDF_DIR)/include

EXEC = CNG_WRFCHEM_EMI
OBJS = module_CNG_WRFCHEM_EMI_lib.o \
       CNG_WRFCHEM_EMI.o

${EXEC} : ${OBJS}
        ${F90} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS}

.f90.o:
        ${F90} -c ${INCLUDE_MODULES} $<

clean:
        rm -f ${EXEC} ${OBJS} *.mod
```

The error message is:

```
 make: *** No rule to make target `module_CNG_WRFCHEM_EMI_lib.o', needed by `CNG_WRFCHEM_EMI'.  Stop.
```

All the files are in the same directory as the picture shows:

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make doesn't know that `.f90` is a suffix, so your suffix rule is not valid.  It's not enough to just declare a suffix rule if make doesn't know about the suffix.  If you want to use suffix rules, you also have to add the new suffix with the `.SUFFIXES` pseudo-target, like this:

```
.SUFFIXES: .f90
```

Or you can use pattern rules, which don't require this (but are GNU make-specific):

```
%.o : %.f90
        ${F90} -c ${INCLUDE_MODULES} $<
```